# How to keep together controls of td tabel's

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want to keep together all controls of (td) it means when zoom percent of my browser changed, all controls of (td) are in a line

```
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input class='required' data-bind='value: ProductName, uniqueName: true ' style="float: left; width: 200px" />
                                    <input class='required' data-bind='value: ProductCode, uniqueName: true' style="float: left; width: 100px" />
                                    <input class='required' data-bind='value: ProductId, uniqueName: true' style="display: none; float: left; width: 100px" />
                                </td>
                                <td> </td>
                                <td> </td>
                                <td> </td>
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                <td> </td>
                           </tr>
```

Before zoom is correct :
[image]
After zoom isn't correct :
[image]

Please help me how to set style sheet of controls that resizing zoom of browser no effect of style.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable code? In here or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting width in relative units like percentages (100%) or ems (em) instead of pixels? Maybe it is needed as well to give a relative size to the table or its container.